# How to Configure the Website in JavaScript to Open Only on Android and IOS Phones

Tags: java, wordpress

how to configure wordpress to open only on ANDROID and IOS cell phones. (I don't want the site to open on Windows, Linux or Mac browsers)

My website is a Wordpress - I didn't find plugins or anything related
someone help me

Comment: Why do mean by "open"? In the smartphone browsers? If it doesn't "open", what is the expected behaviour? Why there is tag "java", is there some Java context you could provide with? Question needs more clarity so community can answer.